# Unable to get value of the property 'chatHub': object is null or undefined

Tags: signalr

I have an web app that I integrate SignalR for chat but I got error
"Unable to get value of the property 'chatHub': object is null or undefined"

Below are the details...

in ASP.Net UserControl

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Css/JQueryUI/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<link href="../Classes/SignalRChat/Css/ChatStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Classes/SignalRChat/Css/JQueryUI/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Css/gradients.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Css/MainCss.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    setScreen(false);

    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
    var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub; //THIS GETS THE ERROR
```

in my startup

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Akr.Web.Classes.SignalRChat.SignalRChatStartup))]

namespace Akr.Web.Classes.SignalRChat
{
    public class SignalRChatStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

in my hub

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace Akr.Web.Classes.SignalRChat
{
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        //... some methods...
    }
}
```

How can I make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you only include the jquery.signalR-*.min.js script once after the jQuery script.

Also ensure that the server is responding with a script from "signalr/hubs". If you are getting a 404, perhaps you should be loading the script from "/signalr/hubs" instead (notice the non-relative path).

Lastly, ensure that your inline JS shows up after the jQuery/SignalR related scripts in your HTML.

Here are some more troubleshooting docs: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting#other

Answer (score -1):

I think the solution could be the same as posted on  [Cannot read property 'chatHub' of undefined SignalR Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178408/cannot-read-property-chathub-of-undefined-signalr-hub/36826552#36826552), check you have the app.MapSignalR(); in  Startup.cs class. See more [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/releases/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20)